# Is $z=x^2$ a cylinder?

Tags: calculus, geometry, conic-sections, 3d

I'm studying multi variable calculus, we are researching about cylinders. And my teacher says that there are not only cylinders with a circular base, that there can be cylinders with a triangular base (which according to me are prisms) or open cylinders (defined by $z = x ^ 2$ for example).

Is this info correct?

Comment: I don't find something about this on my algebra book, there cilinders are only.... cilinders (defined with ecuations like X^2 + Y^2 = 1)

Comment: Did your teacher give a precise definition of "cylinder" ?

Comment: The teacher is talking in 3D

Comment: Nop he didn't give us a definition

Comment: It does rather depend on the definition of "cylinder". It can be the case that words we understand in a simple way in basic work take on a wider definition when things get more advanced. I'm not saying that is right here, but in the equation you have given $y$ is unconstrained (assuming three dimensions). Two questions arise: is it useful to extend the definition in this way (if yes, go with it): is the operative definition in your class used widely by other mathematicians (if no, take care outside your own class).

Comment: Thank you, I never use math exchange before, it is awesome <3

Comment: @Paolo Donato Navarro - In reference to user's answer, the definition of "cylinder" in Wikipedia is "A cylindrical surface is a surface consisting of all the points on all the lines which are parallel to a given line and which pass through a fixed plane curve in a plane not parallel to the given line." This definition does not require the curve to be closed, like an ellipse or a circle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is a [cylinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder#Cylindrical_surfaces) (i.e. a *cylindrical surface*) with the parabola $z=x^2$ as right section (*directrix*) traced out along $y$ axis (*generatrix*).

[image]

[image credit](http://citadel.sjfc.edu/faculty/kgreen/vector/block1/func/node14.html)

Comment: Thank you, the wikipedia about cylinders in spanish is not that usefull.

Comment: @PaoloDonatoNavarro Ah ok! You can update it by this source! You are welcome. Bye

Answer (score 2):

**Cylindrical Surface** is a curved surface which we get by parallel translation of a line, the *generating line* or *generator* along a curve, the so-called *directing curve* (Fig. 1).

**Cylinder** is a solid bounded by a cylindrical surface with a closed directing curve, and by two parallel bases cut out from two parallel planes by the cylindrical surface.

**Figure 1**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, this community is awesome :o